# VBA: extracting text from PDF files without the Acrobat library or opening the document in Word

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-office, acrobat, text-extraction

Does anyone know of any libraries/shell scripts to extract specific text from PDF files (in standard format) to Excel via VBA? Limitations: I do not have the full Acrobat package/VBA reference and do not want to rely on their library. I have PDF24 and PDFXchange Editor.

Appreciated.

EDIT: So after googling and discording a bit I have been directed towards a parsing solution based on [XPFReader](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) and the related [VBA Macro](https://gist.github.com/darkoverlordofdata/11222959).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't load the pdf into word and work from the word document.

Comment: The reason is because it's quite slow, and also half of the time I'm working via remote server which makes it even slower. Obviously I'm ready to resort to that for lack of better alternatives if absolutely needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you freeflow.  You solved all my problems.  I never knew that Word could open PDFs directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you propably can use Powerquery to find the text. Powerquery now allows for pdf-Import.

Comment: You are right. I eventually learned to extract all kinds of information from PDFs by dynamically calling Power Query from VBA.

Answer (score 1):

If it is any help, I have done this in a very twisted manner before excel allowed the pdf extraction:

```
    'Open Pdf from filepath in spreadsheet
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FilePath
    'Wait 1 sec for pdf to open with default reader (acrobat reader in my case)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
    'Select PDF content
SendKeys ("^a")
    'Copy PDF Content
SendKeys ("^c")
    'Close PDF
SendKeys ("%{F4}")
     'Bring Excel to front and activate desired sheet
AppActivate("MicroSoft Excel")
Sheets("Pdf Analysis").Activate
     'Paste pdf content
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

This is not very robust though:

- You won't be able to use your computer while the code runs (if you change the focus while the code runs, it will end up up selecting, copying or closing the wrong things with the "SendKeys").
- You can't debug this code with the debugger open. If you do so, the pdf content will be pasted in your code..
- If you need to do this on many pdfs in one shot, I would advise adding pauses to make sure your pdf reader has time to open and close before selecting and copying.
  I ran this on a list of 1000+ PDFs and I had to have a 2 seconds pause on opening + a 2 second pause on closing for it to not crash.

Comment: I think in the long run I'll just try to learn Postscript to parse pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any freeware .dll libraries per se, but there are plenty of cheap alternatives to Adobe Acrobat out there.  NUANCE Power PDF is an application that adds a custom add-on Tab to the Excel Ribbon allowing an end-user to .PDF a spreadsheet or a doc from Excel or Word.
[image: Nuance by KoFax]

Comment: Thanks for this, though my goal isn't exactly to extract whole PDFs into Excel, but rather to perform specific actions, basically, renaming PDF files based on strings found in them. We're talking about dozens of bank payment confirmations which typically are named 'gibberish', which I would like to automatically rename to something more sensible, like a payment description + date + amount paid.

Comment: Have you tried windows script hosting language to rename these .PDF files, clean up the gibberish, and make the names more sensible?  Or VBScripting?  I've used VB Script to do something similar for Bank files for Hertz that we received in the past.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the script of 'real' VB, though, I would love to familiarize myself with them more, though my schedule is quite tight. I'm looking for a rather quick solution akin to sendkeys - find a keyword emulating ctrl+f and then copy-paste via clipboard, or an intermediate temporary Excel file in between.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above method, as well as just opening the PDF in Word. The problem with opening the PDF in Word is that it has a size limitation as to how big the PDF can be. The Copy Method could also burden resources. I prefer Excel.

I have automated the Get Data > PDF File in Excel PowerQuery... You can do all of the ETL in PowerQuery, load the results to a Worksheet, then connect to the Worksheet.

There are any number of 3rd party tools, that have VBA plug-ins. One that I use is called Import Wizard by BesideSoftware. You can map PDFs for import into Access or Excel. It can also be embedded to run silently in VBA.